How to solve Zephyr sample build Ninja error? "multiple outputs aren't (yet?) supported by depslog"
I am trying to build a sample application from Zephyr SDK but I'm getting this Ninja error for different samples and boards. I'm on Windows10 and using the latest packages as recommended in Zephyr Getting Started guide.
How is this error solved? ←[0mninja: error: build.ninja:790: multiple outputs aren't (yet?) supported by depslog; bring this up on the mailing list if it affects you
Any help would be appreciated!
Full build code output:
>west build -b frdm_k64f samples\hello_world -p
-- west build: making build dir E:\zephyrproject\zephyr\build pristine
-- west build: generating a build system
Loading Zephyr default modules (Zephyr base).
-- Application: E:/zephyrproject/zephyr/samples/hello_world
-- CMake version: 3.29.5
-- Found Python3: C:/Users/AKSHAY JAMES/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe (found suitable version "3.12.0", minimum required is "3.8") found components: Interpreter
-- Cache files will be written to: E:/zephyrproject/zephyr/.cache
-- Zephyr version: 3.7.0-rc1 (E:/zephyrproject/zephyr)
-- Found west (found suitable version "1.2.0", minimum required is "0.14.0")
-- Board: frdm_k64f, qualifiers: mk64f12
-- ZEPHYR_TOOLCHAIN_VARIANT not set, trying to locate Zephyr SDK
-- Found host-tools: zephyr 0.16.8 (E:/zephyr-sdk-0.16.8)
-- Found toolchain: zephyr 0.16.8 (E:/zephyr-sdk-0.16.8)
-- Found Dtc: C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/dtc.exe (found suitable version "1.5.0", minimum required is "1.4.6")
-- Found BOARD.dts: E:/zephyrproject/zephyr/boards/nxp/frdm_k64f/frdm_k64f.dts
-- Generated zephyr.dts: E:/zephyrproject/zephyr/build/zephyr/zephyr.dts
-- Generated devicetree_generated.h: E:/zephyrproject/zephyr/build/zephyr/include/generated/zephyr/devicetree_generated.h
-- Including generated dts.cmake file: E:/zephyrproject/zephyr/build/zephyr/dts.cmake
Parsing E:/zephyrproject/zephyr/Kconfig
Loaded configuration 'E:/zephyrproject/zephyr/boards/nxp/frdm_k64f/frdm_k64f_defconfig'
Merged configuration 'E:/zephyrproject/zephyr/samples/hello_world/prj.conf'
Configuration saved to 'E:/zephyrproject/zephyr/build/zephyr/.config'
Kconfig header saved to 'E:/zephyrproject/zephyr/build/zephyr/include/generated/zephyr/autoconf.h'
-- Found GnuLd: e:/zephyr-sdk-0.16.8/arm-zephyr-eabi/arm-zephyr-eabi/bin/ld.bfd.exe (found version "2.38")
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: E:/zephyr-sdk-0.16.8/arm-zephyr-eabi/bin/arm-zephyr-eabi-gcc.exe
Load components for MK64F12:
driver_common component is included.
driver_reset component is included.
device_CMSIS component is included.
CMSIS_Include_core_cm component is included.
device_system component is included.
driver_uart component is included.
driver_port component is included.
driver_sysmpu component is included.
-- Configuring done (23.1s)
-- Generating done (0.9s)
-- Build files have been written to: E:/zephyrproject/zephyr/build
←[92m-- west build: building application
←[0mninja: error: build.ninja:790: multiple outputs aren't (yet?) supported by depslog; bring this up on the mailing list if it affects you

←[91mFATAL ERROR: command exited with status 1: 'C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE' --build 'E:\zephyrproject\zephyr\build'
←[0m

Tried installing latest packages as recommended in getting started guide.
